# Enlarge markers on Octave rlocus

Tags: octave

Is it possible to make the markers (zeros and poles) from rlocus on Octave?

I've found the following answer, but the file that is supposed to be modified does not seem to be used anymore, or at least I wasn't able to find it with locate on Linux.

https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/372728/octave-rlocus-format-ploles-and-zero

This is the code I'm using to generate the plot.

```
pkg load control;
s = tf ('s');
GH = (s + 1)/(s*(s + 2))
rlocus (GH);
```

This is the plot generated by the code:

[image: Bad plot with small markers]

But the poles and zeros are almost invisible on the standard plot.

Thanks in advance for any responses.

Answer (score 0):

From within octave, type

```
which rlocus
```

on the terminal.

This will tell you the location of the file in your current octave / control-package installation.

You can then proceed and edit the file as per the instructions of the previous post.